# Javascript requires making a copy of this?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In order to pass a value out of the ajax() success callback, I had to do this:

```
var a = this;
```

And then in `success()`:

```
a.myresult = result;
```

Why is it necessary to make a copy of this? When I tried this.myresult, it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the context of your ajax callback, the this keyword has changed context.

Outside your method, it referred to some object. Inside the callback, it refers to the jQuery object (since the method is invoked in the context of a jQuery object).

Comment: where did you read anything about jQuery? javascript isnt jQuery oO

Comment: An error on my part. jQuery is so common that I immediately went for it. The context is going to be the context of what is executing the function. The important point is that `this` is not a constant reference; it always refers to the object containing the currently executing code.

Comment: If you'd work that into your answer properly I'd gladly give you +1 for the most meaningful answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your code, but my guess is you're using "this" in the context of an anonymous function, so "this" refers to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is only meaningful within context. That context within the object's code.